# I am trying to write a program using A Coupled Spring-Mass System . Solve Using ODE's

Tags: python, numpy, runge-kutta

I am trying to write a program using A Coupled Spring-Mass System . Solve Using ODE's

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kitchen1 = 2.0
kitchen2 = 2.0
money1 = 2.0
money2 = 2.0
walk1 = 5.0
walk2 = 5.0
Lenon1 = 2.0
Lenon2 = 2.0

def f1(x1, v1, x2, v2, t):
return v1

def f2 (x1, v1, x2, v2, t):
    return ((-kitchen1/money1)*(x1-Lenon1)) + (kitchen2/money1*(x2-x1-walk1- Lenon2))

def f3(x1, v1, x2, v2, t):
return v2

def f4(x1, v1, x2, v2, t):
     return (-kitchen2/money2) * (x2-x1-walk1-Lenon2)

def rk4_gen(x1_arr, v1_arr, x2_arr, v2_arr, t_arr, h):
x1, v1, x2, v2, t  = t_arr[0], x1_arr[0], v1_arr[0], x2_arr[0], v2_arr[0]

for i in range(1,len(t)):
    t, h = t[i-1], t[i]-t[i-1]  

    k11 = h*f1(x1, v1, x2, v2, t)
    k12 = h*f2(x1, v1, x2, v2, t)
    k13 = h*f3(x1, v1, x2, v2, t)
    k14 = h*f4(x1, v1, x2, v2, t)


    k21 = h*f1(x1+k11/2.0, v1+k12/2.0,x2+k13/2.0,v2+k14/2.0, t+h/2.0)
    k22 = h*f2(x1+k11/2.0, v1+k12/2.0,x2+k13/2.0,v2+k14/2.0, t+h/2.0)
    k23 = h*f3(x1+k11/2.0, v1+k12/2.0,x2+k13/2.0,v2+k14/2.0, t+h/2.0)
    k24 = h*f4(x1+k11/2.0, v1+k12/2.0,x2+k13/2.0,v2+k14/2.0, t+h/2.0)

    k31 = h*f1(x1+k21/2.0, v1+k22/2.0,x2+k23/2.0,v2+k24/2.0, t+h/2.0)
    k32 = h*f2(x1+k21/2.0, v1+k22/2.0,x2+k23/2.0,v2+k24/2.0, t+h/2.0)
    k33 = h*f3(x1+k21/2.0, v1+k22/2.0,x2+k23/2.0,v2+k24/2.0, t+h/2.0)
    k34 = h*f4(x1+k21/2.0, v1+k22/2.0,x2+k23/2.0,v2+k24/2.0, t+h/2.0)

    k41 = h*f1(x1+k31, v1+k32,x2+k33,v2+k34, t+h)
    k42 = h*f2(x1+k31, v1+k32,x2+k33,v2+k34, t+h)
    k43 = h*f3(x1+k31, v1+k32,x2+k33,v2+k34, t+h)
    k44 = h*f4(x1+k31, v1+k32,x2+k33,v2+k34, t+h)


    x1 = x1 + (k11 + 2*k12 + 2*k13 + k14)/6.0
    v1 = v1 + (k21 + 2*k22 + 2*k23 + k24)/6.0
    x2 = x2 + (k31 + 2*k32 + 2*k33 + k34)/6.0
    v2 = v2 + (k41 + 2*k42 + 2*k43 + k44)/6.0

    x1_arr[i], v1_arr[i], x2_arr[i], v2_arr[i] = x1, v1, x2, v2  

return x1_arr, v1_arr , x2_arr , v2_arr, t_arr
```

---

```
def grafik_ciz(t,y,x_baslik,y_baslik,baslik):
plt.figure(figsize = [12, 9])
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel(x_baslik)
plt.ylabel(y_baslik)
plt.title(baslik)
plt.grid()
plt.show()

ti = 0 
tf = 20 
x1 = 2 
v1 = 0
x2 = 15 
v2 = 0
h = 0.5

t = np.arange(ti,tf+h,h) 
x1 = np.zeros(len(t))
v1 = np.zeros(len(t))
x2 = np.zeros(len(t))
v2 = np.zeros(len(t))


x1[0] = x1i
v1[0] = v1i
x2[0] = x2i
v2[0] = v2i

x1 = rk4_gen(x1_arr, v1_arr, x2_arr, v2_arr, t_arr, h
print x1
```

---

Using 4th order Runge-Kutta method

I need to plot a graph showing both x and y as a function of time from t = 0 to t=20.

error m.ValueError: too many values to unpack

Here is my code so far but not display anything on the graph.

I think, this error is `t = np.arange(ti,tf+h,h)`.
I need to plot a graph showing both x1 and v1 as a function of time from t = 0 to t=20.

Comment: Hey Melek, *ValueError: too many values to unpack* has nothing to do with your actual ODE problem. So please, specify exactly on which line are you receiving this error.

Comment: I have made 2 matrices.But I couldn't get the answer. Can you help me?

Comment: Please correct your function indices, at the moment you repeat `f2`. // The order of arguments also changes with time moving from first to last. This is incompatible. // A correct indentation is crucial in python, use [Ctrl]+K to uniformly mark-indent code blocks.

Comment: k21 = f1(v1[i-1] + k11*t[i-1]/2)
        k22 = f2(x1[i-1] + k12*t[i-1]/2,x2[i-1] + k12*t[i-1]/2)
        k23 = f3(v2[i-1] + k13*t[i-1]/2)
        k24 = f4(x1[i-1] + k14*t[i-1]/2,x2[i-1] + k14*t[i-1]/2)                                                     Thank you...now is 'f' corrected in all..but  i did not understand... (The order of arguments also changes with time moving from first to last. This is incompatible.)

Comment: Where you define `f`, `t` comes first. Where you use `f`, `t` comes last. This will give wrong results.

Comment: will be in the form of def f1 (x1, v1, x2, v2, t): is it correct??

Comment: Then you have to also change your definitions to that form.

Comment: Now move the assignment of the computed value to a place after they were computed, fix the indentation, and adapt the return statement to again return the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from many errors in implementing the algorithm correctly, using consistent function interfaces, using the correct function names etc.

Your reported problem is that you do not unpack the arrays passed to `rk4_gen` in the computation of the single RK4 steps.What you can do without too many changes is to rename the parameters like in

```
def rk4_gen(t_arr, x1_arr, v1_arr, x2_arr, v2_arr, h):
```

(why do you pass `h`? In every step you can compute the correct `h=t[i]-t[i-1]`). Then initialize the running variables

```
    t, x1, v1, x2, v2 = t_arr[0], x1_arr[0], v1_arr[0], x2_arr[0], v2_arr[0]
```

perform the (corrected) RK4 steps and at the end of each step save the computed value into the array

```
def rk4_gen(x1_arr, v1_arr, x2_arr, v2_arr, t_arr, h):
    t, x1, v1, x2, v2 = t_arr[0], x1_arr[0], v1_arr[0], x2_arr[0], v2_arr[0]

    for i in range(1,len(t_arr)):
        # Do the RK4 step, it is from i-1 to i
        t, h = t_arr[i-1], t_arr[i]-t_arr[i-1]
        k11 = h*f1(...)
        ...
        v2 = v_2+(k14+2*k24+2*k34+k44)/6.0
        x1_arr[i], v1_arr[i], x2_arr[i], v2_arr[i] = x1, v1, x2, v2

    return x1_arr, v1_arr , x2_arr , v2_arr, t_arr
```

Note also that your finishing computation has the `k` values in transposed order.

---

You can solve this problem in a much more compact way using the `scipy.integrate` methods, like in

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

def spring_ode(t,u):
    x1,v1,x2,v2 = u
    a1 = ((-kitchen1/money1)*(x1-Lenon1)) + (kitchen2/money1*(x2-x1-walk1- Lenon2))
    a2 = (-kitchen2/money2) * (x2-x1-walk1-Lenon2)
    return [v1,a1,v2,a2]

res = solve_ivp(spring_ode, [ti,tf], [x1i,v1i,x2i,v2i], dense_output=True, rtol=1e-12, atol=1e-14)

h=0.02
t = np.arange(ti,tf+h/2,h) 
u = res.sol(t)
x1,v1,x2,v2 = u
plt.figure(figsize = [8, 5])
plt.plot(t,x1,t,x2); plt.legend(["$x_1$","$x_2$"])
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

with the resulting plot

[image]

Comment: The step computation is where the 3 dots are. What is the position of `t` in the `f`?

Comment: dx1'/dt = v1   ///////////  dv1' =((-k1/m1)*(x1-L1)) + (k2/m1*(x2-x1-w1- L2)) is differential equation

Comment: This is not a mathematics problem, this is a pure coding problem. The parameters here are passed as pure number stack, not as name-value dictionaries. If the order is not the same, the values get assigned wrong in the function.

Comment: I tried to fix the main program above. Would you check. please

Comment: This is a strange error, as the parameter x1_arr passed to rk4_gen is a local variable.

Comment: program updated. i can't print the graph now. please help...Would you check

Comment: The computer is stupid, if that notion even applies. What you put in on one side comes out exactly the same way on the other side. It does not care that you switched the position of the `t` variables. If you return five arrays, then when you assign it to one variable you get a 5-tuple of arrays. If you only want one component, you need to select it specifically.

Comment: I want to draw the graph 'v1' and 'v2' according to the variable 't'.

Comment: thank you so much. but runge kutta 4  with solution needed. I have been working on the solution for about 1 month. There is no article left on the internet.

Comment: Your numbering of the `k` is error-prone. Either vectorize everything, or use `k1x1,...,k4v2` so that you get a visual confirmation that everything is in the right place.